What was the main implementation programming language of old 16-bit Windows versions (Windows 1 - Windows 3.11)?
It seems that MS-DOS was primarily written in assembly even in its last versions.
I understand that new versions of Windows such as the NT-based versions currently in use, and Windows 95 .. ME which were not NT-based but still had a 32-bit API were primarily implemented in C. Of course, some assembly code may have been included, some application programs may have been implemented in C++, and 95 .. ME which still had DOS obviously used assembly for the DOS they were running on.
But, what was the main programming language of old 16-bit Windows versions, from Windows 1 to Windows 3.11? Did they use C, or were they primarily implemented in assembly like MS-DOS?
I consider the main programming language to be the language in which most core operating system lines were written in. Non-essential application programs that are not part of core operating system (but still distributed with it) shouldn't be counted. So for example Program Manager is part of core operating system (because you can't use the operating system without it), but Minesweeper isn't.

Nit-picking, but it is possible to run Windows without Program Manager ;-).

@StephenKitt Come on, I was hoping of you answering this :))

@StephenKitt As I recall it was as easy as just editting win.ini and specifying another program (usually a File Manager) in the shell= line. Windows Commander was my favorite. (Later called Total Commander as Microsoft took offense to the name.)

@Tonny that was exactly it. It worked well with file managers; there were also a number of replacement shells, such as IBM’s Workplace Shell, Calmira, Central Point Desktop...

@Tonny just with one correction, the shell= line is in system.ini.

@StephenKitt I wasn't sure which of the 2. Guessed the wrong one :-)

Before Windows 3, the shell was MS-DOS Executive rather than Program Manager. And Microsoft published a version of that for Windows 3 so that hold-outs could keep using the shell they were familiar with, if they wanted to.

For Win2K, a lot of the drivers were still written in ASM. As I recall, when MS was rewriting drivers to c++ there was still a lot of ASM.

Windows 95 was written in assembler. In fact the low level graphics - the GDI - was almost completely lifted from Windows 3.1

The “core” operating system in Windows 1.0 to 3.11 consists of three modules: GDI, KERNEL, and USER. Add some fonts and a few device drivers (keyboard, mouse, video, and “system” mostly), and you can start Windows and run Windows programs. In Windows 1 and 2, the core pieces of the system, along with the MS-DOS Executive, were assembled into two files, WIN100.BIN/WIN100.OVL or WIN200.BIN/WIN200.OVL, to speed up startup.
It seems that KERNEL is mostly written in assembly language, and GDI and USER are a mixture of C and assembly. Some of the assembly language modules are actually manual translations of C modules into assembly, but after the initial translation the modules were maintained using the assembly language versions.
The device drivers are mostly written in assembly language; this can be seen in the DDK. The VXDs used in Windows 3.x are also mostly written in assembly language. In the 80s and 90s device driver developers were used to programming in assembly language rather than C anyway.
Given that assembly language takes more lines than C to write a given feature, it seems likely that there are more lines of assembly language than C for the core of the operating system in 16-bit versions of Windows, at least initially. I would expect more C code to be added in later releases, but since device drivers and VXDs continued to be written in assembly language, it’s possible that the ratio in the core operating system didn’t change much.
Note that the C compiler scene was evolving at the same time as Windows was initially being developed; Microsoft C was initially a rebranded Lattice C, and the first internally-developed version, 3.0, was available for internal use at Microsoft in 1984, for Windows and Xenix development (according to Wikipedia). So at least for the core parts of Windows 1, which started being demonstrated outside of Microsoft in 1983, there wasn’t an appropriate C compiler; and once significant modules had been written in assembly language, it was probably easier to keep maintaining them in assembly language.
x86 C compilers in the 80s were also not very good at optimising, so a good assembly language programmer could produce code which would be both faster and smaller than that produced by a C compiler. Windows targeted very low-performance systems, so speed and size were critical: Windows 1.03 and 1.04 could run on an 8088 PC with 320KiB of RAM, Windows 2.03 on an 8088 PC with 512KiB of RAM, Windows 3.0 on an 8088 PC with 1MiB of RAM (although that was painful). It was only with Windows 3.1 (in 1992) that support for pre-286 PCs was dropped; Windows 3.11 for Workgroups (late 1993) dropped support for pre-386 PCs.

Another reason why assembly was used was performance. For one, Windows needed to run on extremely (by today's standard) low-powered systems. Windows 3.1 ran on 80286 processors and 1 MB (!) of memory. For another, the C compilers at the time were still very new, and probably not very good at optimizing code. For something as power-hungry as a GUI, handcrafting code in assembly was only way to make things work smoothly.

"Some of the assembly language modules are actually manual translations of C modules into assembly, but after the initial translation the modules were maintained using the assembly language versions."
Do you have a source for this?

@Shaggi it’s hinted at in the BetaWiki page on Windows 1.0, and it’s been confirmed to me by someone familiar with the Windows source code dumps (which apparently have modules showing this pattern dating back to at least Windows 2.0).

Like Windows 95, Windows 1.x - 3.x were written in Microsoft C, with some assembly in the kernel.  Program Manager, for example, is written in C.
Windows 95 is derived from Windows 3; while Windows 95 has a new interface and 32-bit API, under the hood the kernel (KRNL386.EXE) shares more with Windows 3.x than it does with NT.

Apart from BASIC, C was at least initially the dominant application language, with the oft-repeated mantra of MAKE IS YOUR FRIEND.

I suppose Windows 1.0 was written in the rebadged Lattice C rather than the home-grown Microsoft C.

It wasn't just the kernel that contained portions written in assembly. Portions of all the main operating system modules were written in assembly. Even portions of GDI were, for example, written in assembly. But, this nitpick aside, the answer is broadly correct: the majority of 16-bit Windows was written in C, with (surprisingly large) portions implemented in x86 assembly. That remained true for Windows 9x, with the amount of assembly code reduced compared to 16-bit Windows. In the 16-bit Windows ecosystem, the primary programming language for application developers was also C.

@CodyGray when you say "majority ... was written in C", is that in terms of the resultant object code, or do you dispute Steven Kitt's claim that "it seems likely that there are more lines of assembly language than C"?

@CodyGray The GDI innWin95 was 95% the same as the GDI in Win3.x which means, of course that it was written in 16 bit assembler.
